# Cómo comparar un Array con un String? Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, string, bucle-for

estaría necesitando si alguien me puede dar una mano y explicarme como comparar el contenido de un Array con un String, o bien, cuál otro método más óptimo puedo utilizar. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que el contenido de una variable (llamada Palabra, en este caso) pueda ser solamente introducido en mayusculas, por lo que cree un Array con las letras del abecedario en minúscula. Adjunto código para que se entienda mejor. Estoy iniciando en todo el mundo de la programación, por lo que es muy probable que el problema sea mas fácil de resolver de lo que me imagino.
Desde ya, gracias.

```
let palabra = prompt('Palabra Solo en mayuscula');
let letrasMinusc = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',
                    'i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o',
                    'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];


function comprobarPalabra() {}
    let i = 0;

    for (i; i < letrasMinusc.length; i++) {
    }; // itera entre el array del abecedario

    if (letrasMinusc[i] === palabra) {
        console.log ('Tiene minusculas');
    } else {
        console.log ('Está en mayusculas')
    } // comprueba igualdad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se resuelve con expresiones regulares: [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)

```js
let palabra = prompt('Palabra Solo en mayuscula');

// expresion regular que encuentra solo letras en mayuscula
var regex = /^[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/
// ^ indica que se buscará el patrón desde el inicio de la cadena
// $ indica que se buscará el patrón hasta el final de la cadena
// [A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ] rango en mayúsculas, incluyendo Ñ y letras con acento
// + cualquier combinación de caracteres del rango 

function comprobarPalabra() {
  // se llama al método test(), devuelve falso si algun caracter
  // no está dentro del patron [A-Z] (solo mayusculas)
  if(!regex.test(palabra)){
    console.log("tiene caracteres que no son mayúscula");
  }else{
    console.log("está en mayúsculas");
    }
}

comprobarPalabra();
```

Comment: Cierto, no lo consideré. Gracias.